# Why is my model generating this error on save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting an error message whenever I try to save a record. I have no clue what is causing this error. After googling around, it sounded like this had something to do with Active Storage, but I'm really not using it at all in this app.

My model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :chat_rooms, :join_table => :chat_rooms_and_users
    has_secure_password

    before_create :generate_nickname

    def generate_nickname
        puts "here"
        self.nickname = "rando_" + rand(99..999).to_s
    end

    def join_room room_name = nil
        if !room_name
            chat_room = ChatRoom.default_room
        else
            chat_room = ChatRoom.find_by name: room_name
        end
        chat_room.users << self unless chat_room.users.include?(self)
    end

    def self.find_or_create_by_client_token client_token
        @user = self.find_by(client_token: client_token)
        if not @user
            @user = self.new
            @user.client_token = client_token
            @user.chat_rooms << ChatRoom.default_room
        end
        @user.online = true
        @user.save # this is the line that generates the error
        return @user
    end
end
```

The Error:

```
There was an exception - URI::GID::MissingModelIdError(Unable to create a Global ID for User without a model id.)
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/globalid-0.4.2/lib/global_id/uri/gid.rb:167:in `validate_model_id'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/globalid-0.4.2/lib/global_id/uri/gid.rb:151:in `set_model_components'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/globalid-0.4.2/lib/global_id/uri/gid.rb:136:in `check_path'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/generic.rb:807:in `path='
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/generic.rb:193:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/generic.rb:137:in `new'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/2.6.0/uri/generic.rb:137:in `build'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/globalid-0.4.2/lib/global_id/uri/gid.rb:92:in `build'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/globalid-0.4.2/lib/global_id/uri/gid.rb:68:in `create'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/globalid-0.4.2/lib/global_id/global_id.rb:15:in `create'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/globalid-0.4.2/lib/global_id/identification.rb:8:in `to_global_id'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/globalid-0.4.2/lib/global_id/identification.rb:13:in `to_gid_param'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.4.3/lib/action_cable/connection/identification.rb:39:in `block in connection_gid'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.4.3/lib/action_cable/connection/identification.rb:37:in `map'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.4.3/lib/action_cable/connection/identification.rb:37:in `connection_gid'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.4.3/lib/action_cable/connection/identification.rb:29:in `connection_identifier'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.4.3/lib/action_cable/connection/internal_channel.rb:15:in `subscribe_to_internal_channel'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.4.3/lib/action_cable/connection/base.rb:170:in `handle_open'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.4.3/lib/action_cable/server/worker.rb:60:in `block in invoke'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.4.3/lib/action_cable/server/worker.rb:41:in `block in work'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:109:in `block in run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.4.3/lib/action_cable/server/worker/active_record_connection_management.rb:16:in `block in with_database_connections'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.4.3/lib/action_cable/connection/tagged_logger_proxy.rb:24:in `block in tag'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.4.3/lib/action_cable/connection/tagged_logger_proxy.rb:24:in `tag'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.4.3/lib/action_cable/server/worker/active_record_connection_management.rb:16:in `with_database_connections'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.4.3/lib/action_cable/engine.rb:62:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.4.3/lib/action_cable/engine.rb:57:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Engine>'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `instance_exec'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.4.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:136:in `run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.4.3/lib/action_cable/server/worker.rb:40:in `work'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.4.3/lib/action_cable/server/worker.rb:58:in `invoke'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actioncable-5.2.4.3/lib/action_cable/server/worker.rb:53:in `block in async_invoke'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:353:in `run_task'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:342:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:325:in `loop'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:325:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:324:in `catch'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.6/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:324:in `block in create_worker'
```

`ApplicationRecord`:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

`ChatRoom`:

```
class ChatRoom < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => :chat_rooms_and_users
  has_many :messages
  validates_uniqueness_of :name

  DEFAULT_ROOM_NAME = "General"

  def self.default_room
    chat_room = ChatRoom.find_by name: self::DEFAULT_ROOM_NAME
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you have in `ApplicationRecord` and `ChatRoom`?

Comment: I've added those to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe somehow you are invoking a broadcast of newly created data to action cable. It takes an instance of `User` class and tries to convert it to [GID](https://github.com/rails/globalid) but to do it successfully you have to have the instance saved in DB to have ID.
`User` model has [has_secure_password](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) in it, by default it requires a password to be set. In `find_or_create_by_client_token` you create a user without a password it might cause validation to fail.
You can debug it like this:

```
def self.find_or_create_by_client_token client_token
  @user = self.find_by(client_token: client_token)
  if not @user
    @user = self.new
    @user.client_token = client_token
    @user.chat_rooms << ChatRoom.default_room
  end
  @user.online = true
  @user.valid?
  puts @user.errors
  return @user
end
```

Try to change `has_secure_password` to `has_secure_password validations: false` or add some code to fill `password` and `password_confirmation` fields.